# Select a gender dominated group from a pupulation where one gendergroup has lower average salary but higher jobPoints

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, relational-database, conditional-statements

I have two tables:
**Table One**: columns – GroupName and GroupJobPoints.
**Table two** has this columns of interest here – GroupName (fk_key) reference to Table One, Person_ID, Gender, Salary.

I want to see from my database:
1)  Get GroupName who is dominated by one gender (=> 60 % of one gender) – GO On with this groups.
2)  Compare this gender dominated groups GroupJobPoints. And if the difference in GroupJobPoints is in range 4 % - compare the male groups to the females group.
3)  Compare the average salary of the male groups with the average salary to the female groups in this 4 % range. If the male group has higher group average salary compared to the female Group - Then I want to know that and have it displayed.

Example: 
1)  Group 1 has 250 males and 50 females in the group. Group 2 has 20 males and 300 females. Both group is dominated by on gender, GO ON
2)  Group 1 has 2 000 points and Group 2 has 1 950 points. The difference is in range 4 % and one Group is dominated by male and one Group is dominated by female. GO ON.
3)  Group 1 has average salary = 25 000 and Group 2 has average salary = 22 000. I want this displayed because the male Group has lower jobpoints but higher average salary and that is Little bit strange for me :-).

How I can get this by SQL-code. I use MS SQL-server Express 2012. I assume there will be some joins and where clauses and so on and the code will be in step by step in some respect but I don´t figure it out how I will do this. can someone please help me with is and I´m sure I will learn a lot by this.

Comment: School work? Any specific dbms? What have you tried so far? Sample data and expected output?

Comment: This is not a schoolwork, rather a jobwork, but thanks anyway. What I have tried is really nothing because I dont know so much about SQL YET but I´m learning and is trying to learn. But if I am disqualified by that so I will. But I have done a database on my own and that is a big thing for me.

Comment: Sample data -- structured as a table -- and desired results would help a lot.  Trying to figure out what you are trying to do from the third paragraph is not easy.

Comment: I have 46 Groups with different Points from 1 500 to 19 000 Points. All gropus have different sizes of men and women. The 4 % range is rolling so the statement will be something where:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t1 as (
    select
        one.GroupName,
        one.GroupJobPoints,
        (select cast(count(1) as float) from TableTwo where GroupName=one.GroupName and Gender='M')/(select cast(count(1) as float) from TableTwo where GroupName=one.GroupName) FracMale,
        (select avg(Salary) from TableTwo where GroupName=one.GroupName) AvgSalary
    from
        TableOne one
)
select
    m.GroupName,
    m.GroupJobPoints,
    m.AvgSalary,
    m.FracMale,
    f.GroupName,
    f.GroupJobPoints,
    f.AvgSalary,
    f.FracMale
from
    t1 m
    cross join t1 f
where
    m.FracMale>=0.60
    and f.FracMale<=0.40
    and abs(f.GroupJobPoints-m.GroupJobPoints)/m.GroupJobPoints<=0.04
    and m.AvgSalary>f.AvgSalary
;
```

Test data:

```
if object_id('TableTwo') is not null drop table TableTwo;
if object_id('TableOne') is not null drop table TableOne;
create table TableOne (GroupName varchar(32), GroupJobPoints float, primary key (GroupName) );
create table TableTwo (GroupName varchar(32) references TableOne(GroupName), Person_ID int, Gender char(1), Salary float, primary key (Person_ID) );

insert into TableOne (GroupName, GroupJobPoints ) values ('1',2000);
insert into TableOne (GroupName, GroupJobPoints ) values ('2',1950);

declare @PersonID int = 0;
declare @i int;

set @i = 0; while (@i < 250) begin set @PersonID=@PersonID+1; insert into TableTwo (GroupName, Person_ID, Gender, Salary ) values ('1',@PersonID,'M',25000); set @i=@i+1; end;
set @i = 0; while (@i < 50) begin set @PersonID=@PersonID+1; insert into TableTwo (GroupName, Person_ID, Gender, Salary ) values ('1',@PersonID,'F',25000); set @i=@i+1; end;

set @i = 0; while (@i < 20) begin set @PersonID=@PersonID+1; insert into TableTwo (GroupName, Person_ID, Gender, Salary ) values ('2',@PersonID,'M',22000); set @i=@i+1; end;
set @i = 0; while (@i < 300) begin set @PersonID=@PersonID+1; insert into TableTwo (GroupName, Person_ID, Gender, Salary ) values ('2',@PersonID,'F',22000); set @i=@i+1; end;
```

Output from running all of the above:

[image: output]

Comment: +1.  Nice solution.  Suggest changing f.FracMale<0.40 to isnull(f.FracName,0)<0.40. to handle the case where a group doesn't have any Males.  You can also simply the cast and count combination with sum(1.00).

Comment: Thanks I have tested your solution with my data and I have some questions. How do I get screenshot in here to show you?

Comment: I tried your code in SQL Fiddle  and I get a message that says invalid object name Table one. Can you see why http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/2202

Comment: See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/2210. The main problem was that you hadn't included the test code I wrote which defines the actual tables (`TableOne` and `TableTwo`) and inserts test data into them. You also changed the alias in the `select` query from `one` to `Tableone`, which would have caused it to fail anyway. Final note, sqlfiddle seems to execute each line in a separate batch, and since the `declare` statement only declares a variable within the current batch, I had to combine all statements from the first declare to the last while loop into one line.